# invalidcastexception when trying to convert from ListBox object to MyListBox : ListBox object in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I use a ListBox in my code to store some csv files selected by the user:

```
<ListBox x:Name="emailsFilesListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="10,254,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147"/>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs I use a private class to extend System.Windows.Controls.ListBox:

```
private class MyListBox : System.Windows.Controls.ListBox
        {
            public string[] FullFilesPathsList { get; set; }
            public MyListBox() : base()
            {
            }
        }
```

Inside an event handler in MainWindow.xaml.cs I have the following code:

```
  private void emailsAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = true;
        dlg.Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            MyListBox myListBoxWithEmailsFiles = new MyListBox();
            myListBoxWithEmailsFiles = (MyListBox)emailsFilesListBox;
            myListBoxWithEmailsFiles.FullFilesPathsList = dlg.FileNames;
            ....................................

        }
    }
```

Trying to perform the conversion "myListBoxWithEmailsFiles = (MyListBox)emailsFilesListBox;" leads to an InvalidCastException. Could you tell me why is this possible?

Comment: emailsFilesListBox is `ListBox`, not `MyListBox`. Every `MyListBox` is `ListBox` but not the other way round

Comment: Why isn't the downcast allowed in that case?

Comment: because in XAML it's not created as `MyListBox`, but `ListBox`. You create `MyListBox ` class but not use it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If there are modifications to be done in XAML (just changing the tag ListBox to MyListBox didn't fix anything, of course) in order to make things work, I look forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MyListBox` instead of `ListBox` by changing the scope of your class from `private` to `public`, and then changing your XAML accordingly:

```
<nameOfYourWpfProject:MyListBox x:Name="emailsFilesListBox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="10,254,0,0" Grid.Row="1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147"/>
```

You'll have to add something like this to your main `Window` tag:

```
xmlns:nameOfYourWpfProject="clr-namespace:NameOfYourWpfProject"
```

---

In general, you can't cast a base type to a derived type like that. Another option would be to pass the `ListBox` in the ctor to your class, and then create properties to expose the `ListBox` properties you want to access.

```
private class MyListBox : System.Windows.Controls.ListBox
{
    public string[] FullFilesPathsList { get; set; }

    public MyListBox(ListBox listBox)
    {
        this.listBox = listBox;
    }

    private ListBox listBox;

    public string Name { get { return listBox.Name; } }
}
```

That shouldn't be necessary in this case, if you just use `MyListBox` in place of `ListBox`.